# If statement in a WHERE clause for between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a script that counts the number of doses a client has had between their start date and 180 days out.

Now i am trying to have some form of an IF (or CASE) statement in the where clause so its either between the first date and 180 days out OR if that 180 days exceeds 6/30/20, then just do the count between start date and 6/30/20.

In my research i couldnt find anything about using an IF else (or CASE) with dates, in the WHERE function.

This is my current script in SQL Server

```
    SELECT
        t.clinic,
        t.display_id,
        m.FirstDate,
        DATEADD(DAY,180,MIN(take_on_date)) AS Days_180,
        COUNT(t.dose_number) AS Doses

FROM (SELECT CLINIC
              , display_id
              , MIN(TAKE_ON_DATE) AS FirstDate
           FROM factMedHist

         GROUP BY Clinic, display_id
            ) AS m

INNER JOIN factMedHist AS t
    ON t.Clinic = m.Clinic     
   AND t.display_id = m.display_id     
 WHERE t.take_on_date 
       BETWEEN m.FirstDate AND DATEADD(DAY,180,m.FirstDate)


GROUP BY t.Clinic, t.display_id,m.FirstDate
```

Comment: Using different terms for the same "thing" is confusing. Which column is your "start date"?

Comment: And "client" is identified by what column (or set of columns)?

Comment: You can't use an `IF` in the `WHERE`, it's not a function, it's logical flow operator. `Case`  (`Switch`) statements are also not available in T-SQL, however, `CASE` expressions do exist; though you shouldn't use these in a `WHERE` as it'll cause the query to be non-SARGable. Stick to standard Boolean logic with `AND` and `OR`s.

Comment: start date is MIN(TAKE_ON_DATE), which is m.FirstDate. The clients is .display_id

Comment: `AND t.take_on_date < cast('20200621' as date)`

Comment: I would probably just compute the `Days_180` in the derived table since you're using the same expression twice. Might as well refer to it by a meaningful name.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE t.take_on_date BETWEEN m.FirstDate AND DATEADD(DAY,180,m.FirstDate)
OR t.take_on_date > DATEADD(DAY, 180, '20200630')
```

Answer (score 0):

So "start date" = "FirstDate" = "min(TAKE_ON_DATE)". And "Client" = "display_id" but you group and join on the tuple <display_id, Clinic>. I see many struggles in the future based on this unfortunately common issue. Consistent terminology is important.

So here is one take on your issue. A bit verbose to demonstrate what it does. Note also the provision of a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - something that you should provide to encourage others to help. It is a bit of effort you should not expect others to take on just to solve your issues.

You were on the correct path with CASE - but lost it when you started thinking of it as a control-of-flow construct as it is in most other languages. You can compute the startdate and enddate for each client (clinic, display_id)

```
with cte as (select *, 
    min(takedate) over (partition by display_id, clinic order by takedate) as startdate, 
    dateadd(day, 180, min(takedate) over (partition by display_id, clinic order by takedate)) as enddate 
   from @medhist 
)
```

You were doing that - but the problem is that you need reference that end date in the where clause to filter the rows as desired. Like this:

```
where takedate <= case when enddate <= '20200630' then enddate else '20200630' end
```

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=637884567abf8a981df46ec7da5dddfa). Notice that the first take date is irrelevant in the where clause. This is one way to achieve your result. Another obvious approach is to use a conditional sum. That would be good practice if you wanted to increase your knowledge. Depending on your situation one might be more efficient than the other. CTEs are just syntactic sugar but do allow the building of logic in a piece-by-piece approach - something I find can be very helpful in developing a completed tsql statement.